Problem with subprocess.Popen in python 3
I am in the process of revising python 2.7 code to python 3 in the Microsoft Windows 10 environment. I use subprocess in several scripts to parallel process single thread application calls, this approach works very well in 2.7 but in python 3 each Popen opens a CMD window which is really annoying as it takes focus away from the mouse and keyboard; if each process takes 10 seconds and there are 5 to 10 thousand iterations then for the next 13 to 26 hours focus is being stolen making the computer almost unusable for anything else.
Is there something I'm missing in the documentation that would change the behaviour of Popen to just simmer away in the background like it does in 2.7?
The code:
ProcSpawned = False
while not ProcSpawned:
    for ThisIndex in ThreadRange:
        if RunningProcesses[ThisIndex] == None:
            ProcSpawned = True # initialized starting value, this slot is free
        elif RunningProcesses[ThisIndex].poll() != None:
            ProcSpawned = True # this process has terminated, now this slot is free to use
        
        if ProcSpawned:
            FullCommand = Prog2Run + TheseIO
            RunningProcesses[ThisIndex] = subprocess.Popen(FullCommand,stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNUL2)
            break # thread launched, now break out so we don't restart it multiple times

Prog2Run is an executable that is usually run in a CMD window, TheseIO is a list of parameters being passed to the executalbe, FNULL and FNUL2 are os.devnull because I don't care what text or error it generates as I check for failures after all threads have exited (some of the executables generate progress messages on stderr instead of stdout).
